# Use material design icons with Angular ng-repeat list item

Tags: angularjs, material-design

How should I use Material design icons as items in list created using angular ng-repeat? I create example which doesn't work :/

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(country,goals) in items">{{country}}: {{goals}}</li>
         <i class="material-icons">face</i>
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE87C;</i>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/1912/

Comment: hey, i had somes problem with materia icons and angualr js,maybe this  interest you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418580/material-design-lite-rendering-problems-with-angular-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
```

is enough. No need to add custom styles to your css unless you self hosting it.

http://jsfiddle.net/f39hzjuc/